# Make & make install in Asterisk config not complete

Tags: makefile, asterisk, configure, ubuntu-server

I config with `./configure` and make `menuconfig`currently.
but when I run the make command:

```
root@ubuntu:~/asterisk-15.0.0# make
CC="cc" CXX="g++" LD="" AR="" RANLIB="" CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" make -C 
menuselect CONFIGURE_SILENT="--silent" makeopts
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/h26km/asterisk-15.0.0/menuselect'
make[1]: 'makeopts' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/h26km/asterisk-15.0.0/menuselect'
[LD] libasteriskpj.o -> libasteriskpj.so.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:293: recipe for target 'libasteriskpj.so.2' failed
make[1]: *** [libasteriskpj.so.2] Error 1
Makefile:367: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

please help to config it completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

You have install openssl and crypto devel packages.

Answer (score 2):

You need several dependencies for installation, you can do below to get all: [Goto official site to see more](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Checking+Asterisk+Requirements)

Going Inside the Directory

```
cd asterisk-XX.XX.X/contrib/scripts
```

Install dependent package for Asterisk.

```
sudo ./install_prereq install
```